# Installing font in DOMPDF failes

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Is there a reason why I can't install a new font in DOMPDF? It's an uncommon .ttf font, works in Paint, Word, etc but if I install it in DOMPDF it's displayed as installed correctly but wont show up if its included or used in the PDF.

Comment: What is the font (is it available online)? How are you installing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow given link to convert your TTF font in other format and use that format in DOMPDF.
http://www.fonts2u.com/font-converter.html, the idea is if there is any error in TTF file it won;t be get converted in other format and the way you will come to know the exact error.